# Prepositional verb and non-prepositional one of a same object

Tags: grammar

If a prepositional verb and a non-prepositional one have the same object, should I put first the non-prepositional one, or it's not necessary ?
The sentence is
"You should reflect on and examine this case"

Comment: Yes, or you can use parenthetical commas: *"You should reflect on, and examine, this case"* or *"You should examine, and reflect on, this case"*

Comment: Since you'd probably have to examine the case before you can reflect on it, you may want to put it in that order.

Comment: In general, though, if you have two conjuncts and one is longer, the longer one goes second, the shorter is first. That's not a grammar rule; it's just a fact about human communication and perception. Cooper and Ross attribute this principle to Pāṇini in [their classic paper "World Order"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf).